# What is a natural return type in java?

Tags: java, return, return-value, factory

I am reading Joshua Blochs "Effective Java", and it says

> A third advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they can return an object of any subtype of their return type. This gives you great flexibility in choosing the class of the returned object. One application of this flexibility is that an API can return objects without making their classes public. Hiding implementation classes in this fashion leads to a very compact API. This technique lends itself to interface-based frameworks, where interfaces provide natural return types for static factory methods.

Can anyone explain what "natural return types are"? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it means anything specific to java features, syntax, or data types. This is not exactly about java at all, it is about interfaces. The synonym is probably "common", "more intuitive"...

Answer (score 3):

In this context, "natural" simply means natural for the context of the factory method; i.e. what is appropriate or what you would expect.  Intuitive would be another synonym.

This is just normal English usage ... not IT or Java-specific terminology.

Answer (score 2):

A concrete example of this would be something like Guava's `ImmutableList` factory methods.

This has 13 overloads of the `of` method, with increasing numbers of parameters. If you look at [the source of the first 3](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java#L82):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of() {
  return (ImmutableList<E>) EMPTY;
}

public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E element) {
  return new SingletonImmutableList<E>(element);
}

public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E e1, E e2) {
  return construct(e1, e2);
}
```

The zero-arg and two-arg methods actually return an instance of `RegularImmutableList`, which is a subclass of `ImmutableList`; the one-arg method returns an instance of `SingletonImmutableList`.

But is this detail about the subclass relevant to you, the caller? No. It is "natural" that if you call a method that constructs an `ImmutableList`, you get back a reference to an `ImmutableList`.

"Natural" in this sense perhaps means "at an appropriate level of abstraction".

Answer (score 1):

I think that it refers to the class of the factory (which is usually a static method in the class) which doesn't need to instantiate this specific class. However I don't think it is a defined or usually used term.

### Example: Term

```
public abstract class Term {

    public abstract Integer evaluate();

    static Term literal(Integer number) {
        return new Literal(number);
    }

    static Term add(Term left, Term right) {
        return new Addition(left, right);
    }

    private static class Addition extends Term {
        private Term left;
        private Term right;

        public Addition(Term left, Term right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        @java.lang.Override
        public Integer evaluate() {
            return left + right;
        }
    }

    private static class Literal extends Term {
        private Integer number;

        public Literal(Integer number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        @java.lang.Override
        public Integer evaluate() {
            return number;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a class called `Term` with 2 factory methods: `literal` and `add`, which both return a `Term` but a subclass of it. Term itself is not instantable, because it is abstract. To the outer world the inner classes are not visible (they are private). Accessible is just the interface / abstract class `Term`, which is what is referred to in

> One application of this flexibility is that an API can return objects without making their classes public.

I think the "natural class" to return here would be an `Term` and `new` is bound to return an instance of exactly the given type. A factory method can return subtypes.

### Example: Guava

Guava is a library which provides additional collection classes for Java.
One of these is an immutable list. It contains multiple factory methods for specific cases, for example one [for an empty list](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/0cd4e9faa1360da4a343f84cb275d6eda0c5e732/guava-gwt/src-super/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java#L55) and an additional one for [lists which exactly one element](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/0cd4e9faa1360da4a343f84cb275d6eda0c5e732/guava-gwt/src-super/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java#L59).

I don't think the term "natural class" is "official" though. Without the context (and even with it, as we can see here) it is not sure that it is recognized. So I took your question on a more broader scale and explained what the chapter is about.

Comment: *"I don't think the term "natural class" is "official" though."* - precisely!  In my 20+ years of Java programming / spec reading, etc, I don't recall ever seeing the phrase "natural class" used as terminology.  Which is why I reckon that Bloch is just using "natural" as a normal English word.  As one would do ... naturally.

Comment: The question about answering questions is: What do you read from the question and what do you answer. If you take the question literally: There is no "natural class" to the best of my / our knowledge. However there is meaning to the book chapter. I decided to answer that, instead of the literal question. Beeing able to phrase a question correctly is often already part of the answer :)

Comment: The first sentence says - *"I disagree that it is "just english language"*.  I am rebutting that.  Since this is not recognized terminology (official or otherwise) it must be just English.  Obviously, the author has a meaning in mind when he uses those words ... but he is not trying to use or invent terminology here.   But your answer is **saying** that this **is** terminology ... without any supporting evidence.  (Your supposed evidence is actually argumentation, and 100% consistent with the normal English use / sense of the word "natural".)

Comment: I rephrased that sentence. I still think he refers to the specific class of the static factory method. I do see your point though. I don't disagree on that whether the term is defined (I also don't think so). I interpreted "just english" in the sense that it doesn't refer to an programming term, which I think it does.